# What is positive and negative supercoiling?

Tags: genetics, dna, molecular-genetics, human-genetics, supercoiling

Is the following correct?

Positive supercoiling  = the coiling of DNA helix (B-DNA) on itself during intesified coiling of the two DNA stands in *right* handed direction

negative supercoiling  = the coiling of DNA helix(B-DNA) upon itself during uncoiling of the two DNA strands performed in *left* handed direction?

I'm a little confused.

Comment: Think of positive supercoiling as twisting the loop clockwise from the top, while think of negative supercoiling as twisting the loop counterclockwise from the top.

Comment: Positive means left handed or clockwise supercoiling. It results due to overwinding of dsDNA and thus relieve the torsional stress. Whereas the negative supercoil is just the opposite of the earlier.

Comment: The image from the web book seems to be contradictory with the text and the video.
(a) is a left handed helix, so is negative supercoil, (b) is a right handed helix, so is positive supercoil.
Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this [powerpoint](http://www.siumed.edu/%7Ebbartholomew/-lectures/Supercoiling.pdf) from the SIU School of Medicine:

> **Right handed supercoiling** = negative supercoiling (underwinding)
>
> **Left handed supercoiling** = positive supercoiling

And from this Boston University [webpage](https://tandem.bu.edu/knex/supercoil.knex.html):

> If DNA is in the form of a circular molecule, or if the ends are rigidly held so that it forms a loop, then overtwisting or undertwisting leads to the supercoiled state. Supercoiling occurs when the molecule relieves the helical stress by twisting around itself. Overtwisting leads to **postive supercoiling**, while undertwisting leads to **negative supercoiling**.

And finally from [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structural_Biochemistry/Nucleic_Acid/DNA/Supercoiling_and_Nucleosomes#Positive_and_Negative_Supercoilings):

> Positive and Negative Supercoilings
>
> 1. **Positive supercoiling** is the right-handed, double helical form of DNA. It is twisted tightly in a right handed direction until the helix creates knot.
> 2. **Negative supercoiling** is the left-handed, double helical form of DNA.
>
> Although the helix is underwound and has low twisting stress, negative supercoil's knot has high twisting stress. Prokaryotes and Eukaryotes usually have negative supercoiled DNA. Negative supercoiling is naturally prevalent because negative supercoiling prepares the molecule for processes that require separation of the DNA strands. For example, negative supercoiling would be advantageous in replication because it is easier to unwind whereas positive supercoiling is more condensed and would make separation difficult.
>
> Topoisomerases unwind helix to do DNA transcription and DNA replication. After the proteins have been made,the DNA template supercoils by the force to make chromatin. RNA polymerase also influence DNA strand to have two different supercoiled directions. The region RNA polymerase has passed forms negative supercoil while the region RNA polymerase that have not passed forms positive supercoil. By these processes, supercoils are generated.

In the following image from [web-books](http://www.web-books.com/MoBio/Free/Ch7D.htm):

[image]

<sup>**(a)** Positive supercoils (the front segment of a DNA molecule cross over the back segment from left to right). **(b)** Negative supercoils.</sup>

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qj_eYWgQ90k), titled "super coil (positive and negative) formation of DNA" should help you visualize this.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh Does this help clarify it for you at all?

Comment: I read this topic from a book which cleared my doubts and your answer reassured it.Thank you.